# Site scales on InputField Focus, but does not rescale

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a site based on a bootstrap template ( see http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-agency/ )
I am having a problem with the fact that when testing on my mobile device ( iphone 5 ) the whole content scales when an input field gets focus.
After typing in the text and refocusing on other content the site does not rescale back to normal. 
Is there a way to fix this in css or else?
Or is this a problem with iOS ?

Thanks!

Comment: try to add <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"> to the html head

Comment: Please note that using user-scalable=no is very bad for user experience as users won't be able to zoom in on elements on your page. http://www.iheni.com/mobile-accessibility-tip-dont-suppress-pinch-zoom/

Answer (score 1):

This is standard behaviour for iOS. The best way to prevent this is to set the input text size to `16px` or larger. This way the window won't zoom after `:focus`.

There are [other ways](https://vasilis.nl/nerd/prevent-ios-from-zooming-onfocus/) to prevent this behaviour but they have multiple drawbacks.